# How to search Google by specific URL?

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-search-api

I want to search for results from a specific site but only from a specific section of the site, I want to exclude results that have url segments, for example:

**What I want to search for:**

http://domain.com/productx

**What I want to exclude**

http://domain.com/productx/details/further

What query would I use in Google search to get the first results **only** above.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a web service. You may be able to get help on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 17):

```
site:domain.com/productx -domain.com/productx/details/further
```

Eg. search all stack overflow but not unanswered directory:

```
site:stackoverflow.com -stackoverflow.com/unanswered
```

Comment: Have you tried this recently? It is my impression that this (or similar ways to exclude paths) used to work but does not anymore. (The site: still works of course, but excluding the paths does not).

Answer (score 2):

Using [Google advanced search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search) page  and directing it to search on one site only with terms appearing only in the text of the page would not search linked pages.

Comment: is there a specific query using search operators?

Comment: I believe intext is the operator for searching only on page text.

Comment: I know there is inurl also, but how would I use this to exclude certain text or uri segments, i.e. I only want mydomain.com/products and not mydomain.com/products/s..

Comment: The following should provide the functionality to search only on the specific page given and not any domains linked from said page -- allintext: term site:http://www.website.com/index.html    (pardon the formatting as I'm on my phone)